# Is there an equivalent in Karate DSL to the "Finally" block in java?

Tags: karate

I am working with Karate for a couple of months now.
I have noticed that if a test fails , the post-request functions (The functions that are executed after the request has been sent) will not be executed and it can make the other tests in that feature file fail.
So is there an equivalent in Karate to the "Finally" block in Java ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for the `afterScenario` hook. Note that to detect if there is an error, the `errorMessage` will not be null: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks